# Lost PrimeNg styling after upgrade to version 16

Tags: angular, primeng

All of a sudden margin padding font etc of PrimeNg gone crazy when i upgraded my versions to 16 (Both Angular as well as PrimeNg). This is my package.json:

```
{
  ...
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.12",
    ...
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "primeicons": "^6.0.1",
    "primeng": "^16.4.3",
    "primeflex": "^2.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.13",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.12",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.2.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
}
```

**angular.json:**

```
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css"
            ],
```

`npm i` doesn't gives any error. `ng serve` is also perfect. No error on console logs. Functionality is also not impacted but the style is severely damaged. I've a major release coming up next week. Please help.